# How to Round Decimal Result of a Calculated Column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, calculated-columns

I have a calculated column in Oracle that returns a number that is very long because of decimals (ex: 200000.0044068030021345452041589203332645).

Is there a way to convert this to say 200000.00? I tried Round, TO_DECIMAL, CAST. But nothing seems to work.

```
SELECT
CASE
     WHEN TRD = 'FUT'
     THEN
         CASE
             WHEN BUY_SELL = 'BUY' 
             THEN CUR / PRC 
             ELSE -CUR / PRC
         END
     ELSE NULL
END AS UNITS
FROM LAN.Details
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use round

```
  select round(200000.0044068030021345452041589203332645,2) from dual
```

so in your query

```
SELECT
CASE
     WHEN TRD = 'FUT'
     THEN
         CASE
             WHEN BUY_SELL = 'BUY' 
             THEN round( CUR / PRC ,2)
             ELSE round(-CUR / PRC,2)
         END
     ELSE NULL
END AS UNITS
FROM LAN.Details
```

Comment: Not sure how this help. That number was just an example of a result set. I need to apply the round to the whole CASE statement.

Comment: Wow so simple and yet effective. Thank you, that worked great.